# Different behavior of get in Clojure and in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Here is the difference:

```
clj> (get 42 :anything) ; => nil
cljs> (get 42 :anything) ; =>  Error: No protocol method ILookup.-lookup defined for type number: 42
```

I don't know if this is a bug in ClojureScript or an undocumented difference or I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`get`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1404) in `clojure.core` is different from the function [`get`](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L887) in `cljs.core`

The clojure function works on map (and in case you don't pass map it returns then 3rd param or nil if you don't pass 3rd param), the clojurescript function works on any type which has implementation for ILookup protocol

Answer (score 5):

I'm one of the ClojureScript developers. `get` should accept anything, the current behavior of ClojureScript is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

You are misusing `get` here - do you mean to supply a map argument as well?

E.g.,

```
cljs> (get {} 42 :anything)
;=> :anything
```

In Clojure / ClojureScript, `get` assumes a map for the first argument:

```
clj> (doc get)
-------------------------
clojure.core/get
([map key] [map key not-found])
  Returns the value mapped to key, not-found or nil if key not present.
nil
```

Since the underlying implementations are so different, I'd expect to see undocumented uses of functions (in this case, providing a number instead of a map) resulting in different behaviors.

Comment: I just want to call `(get-in some-complex-form [:foo :bar :baz])` without having to check the internals of the form.  And `get-in` uses `get`.